# Using worksheet function in array mode in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write code something like this:

```
Cells(1.1)={application.worksheetfunction.percentilerank(if(range(b:b),b1,range(k:k),k1)}
```

Where column B has a condition that should match B1 for which percentile rank to be calculated of K1 for values in column K.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a cell's `Formula`, or compute its `Value`?

Comment: I want to put computed value in VBA and put it in cell. If i assign formula to cell calculation takes hell lot of time for any changes made and while opening and closing excel. There are 5000 rows which would mean 5000 cells with array if i assign formula to cell

Comment: In general, if you need to compare arrays in VBA as it seems you want to in this example, you need to loop through and do it one at a time (or use the `Evaluate` method).  However, I don't see how to reproduce your problem with no data examples having been provided.  Suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok. Let me explain this further. Column B has various departments of a Company, Column C has name of employees. Column D to J has salary breakup. Column K has monthly gross salary. Total employee 5000. I am supposed to calculate percentile ranking of each employee within their department.

Comment: If I enter formula in cell A1 it would be like ={PERCENTRANK(IF($B:$B=B1,$K:$K,K2))} and drag this for all 5000 employees. Problem is it slows down calculation process. So I am looking for alternate way to handle this.